# IContentRepository vs IContentLoader in EPiServer

Tags: episerver

In EPiServer 7, I have come across 2 different interfaces to get a hold of the EPiServer repository - IContentRepository and IContentLoader.

Example:

```
 var repo = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
```

and:

```
var repo = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
```

Could somebody explain to me when to use one in front of the other?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When to use one in front of the other depends on the *action* you want to perform.

First of all, lets go through their definitions (stated on world.episerver.com)

**IContentRepository**

"*IContentRepository is the primary API that defines repository methods for IContent objects [...] Through the repository, you can perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations and other operations on content instances such as listing and move (that is, instances implementing EPiServer.Core.IContent).*"

**IContentLoader**

"*Describes a service that can be used to read content data objects from a repository*."

As the definition states, IContentLoader is used for reading content, e.g. it does not support all of the CRUD performance. 
Anecdote: The IContentRepository implements the interface IContentLoader.

**Shorter answer:**

Use **IContentRepository** when you plan on *modifying* content/data in the repository.

Use **IContentLoader** when you only plan on *reading* content/data in the repository.

Hope this clarifies it for you!

Comment: Thx @ChrisRun. This surely clarifies it :)